# The_content display a different content from a previous loop

Tags: query-posts, loop, the-content

I have custom template for my homepage. If i just put the_content(); to this template, nothing else, then it will display my text i entered in my admin panel in the editor. But if i have a different loop in my template, its display the content from an other post.

```
    <?php 
    query_posts( array(
            'post_type' => array(
            'movies'
            )
    ));
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            asd
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

So the the_content(); part in the end is displaying the content from the previous loop. What should i do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try rewinding the Loop, via [`rewind_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rewind_posts), between the two loops?

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        asd
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php rewind_posts(); // REWIND THE LOOP! ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but nothing changed. Edit: wp_reset_query() is working, thanks!

Comment: @passatgt I rejected your edit, because it turns this answer into entirely different one. It would be better if you posted code that worked for you as separate answer.